# How to pass through items with certain logic?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, rx.net

I'm looking for a way to pass through items with certain logic. The most obvious answer probably would be to use .Select which is sort of works with most of the cases but I have a special case and the question can be actually rephrased as how to call a certain method after an item is consumed by all subscribers?

I was thinking about an extension looking like this `PassThrough(this IObservable<TSource> obj, Action<TSource, IObserver<TResult>> selector)` and I would use it in the following way

```
.PassThrough((source, observer) => {
   if(source != null) {
      using(var result = new Result(source)) {
         observer.OnNext(result);
      }
   }
});
```

The most important part of this is calling .Dispose for the result object after the object is passed to OnNext in other words after it is consumed by subscribers. I didn't find such extension method. Could somebody give an example how to achieve it with existing Rx.NET API or how to create an extension which will do this, presuming it is possible?

Comment: Problem with the dipose is, I think, you don't know when the object is consumed by subscribers. They might buffer it for all you know, and consume them in batches. OnNext doesn't guarantee that items are processed when the call to OnNext is done.

Comment: Good point but this is probably a single scenario when it won't work if the items somehow buffered after that. If there is no way to resolve this situation clearly let's assume there is no buffering. How to implement PassThrough extension method in this case? Should I use a Subject object inside? What are the general guidelines to implement custom extension methods?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably Observable.Create via an extension method. In your case it may look like the following:

```
public static IObservable<Result> PassThrough(this IObservable<TSource> obj, T source) {
   return Observable.Create(observer => {
      if(source != null) {
         using(var result = new Result(source)) {
            observer.OnNext(result);
            observer.OnCompleted();
         }
      } else {
         observer.OnError(Some Error);
         ...
      }
   })
}
```

Obviously depending on whether you want to keep the stream going, you would omit the OnCompleted() call.

See here for more information on usage of Observable.Create:
http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#CreationOfObservables